# How to fix recipe for target error in Clion?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am receiving following error while executing a program in clion.

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.2.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\two43\CLionProjects\cse\cmake-build-debug --target cse -- -j 2
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable cse.exe
CMakeFiles\cse.dir\build.make:114: recipe for target 'cse.exe' failed
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\cse.dir/objects.a(lecture-2.cpp.obj): in function `main':
C:/Users/two43/CLionProjects/cse/lecture-2.cpp:24: multiple definition of `main'; CMakeFiles\cse.dir/objects.a(lecture-1.cpp.obj):C:/Users/two43/CLionProjects/cse/lecture-1.cpp:19: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [cse.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cse.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cse.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cse.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cse.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cse] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cse' failed
```

Following is the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(cse)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(cse main.cpp lecture-1.cpp lecture-2.cpp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling two files, `cse/lecture-1.cpp` and `cse/lecture-2.cpp`. Both contain a `main` function. You cannot build a single executable with multiple `main` functions.

Make them separate executables by using `add_executable` two times in your CMake definitions. I would show you how if you provided your CMake definitions.

**Edit:** Based on your CMake definitions, use

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(cse)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(lecture-1 main.cpp lecture-1.cpp)
add_executable(lecture-2 main.cpp lecture-2.cpp)
```

This assumes `main.cpp`, despite its name, does not contain *another* `main` function. If it does, you'll need a separate `add_executable` for it too.

Comment: This is my cmake definition```cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(cse)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(cse main.cpp lecture-1.cpp lecture-2.cpp)```

Comment: Edited. Next time, please provide all relevant code in your question.

Comment: @NeelModi: Do not wait "next time": add the code to your **question post**. Among other things, this is a **requirement** of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @flyx so this means everytime I add a new source file to the folder i have to create a new separate executable fot it.

Comment: okay, I am new to stack overflow so still don't know much about how to use it.

Comment: @NeelModi If every source should compile to a seperate executable, then yes, you need to add `add_executable` for it. Whether you *want* it to be a separate executable is up to you, but existence of a `main` function implies you do (since every executable can only have one `main` function).

Comment: @Tsyvarev added the cmake file to the question

Comment: that is necessary ??? the ide cannot make it automatically ?

Comment: @marti_ If it was easily computable for IDEs what to do with C++ sources, we would not need build systems like CMake. Each executable can depend on any number of source files in addition to the file containing the `main` function, and the IDE cannot, in general, know which ones. That is why each needs an explicit `add_executable` that defines its dependencies. If the dependencies are the same for all executables, you can of course use a for loop.

Comment: @flyx yep! it was a problem with "add_executable" apart of main.cpp I added another *cpp files that generated an error something like this add_executable(App main.cpp, another.cpp test.cpp)